# Get specific data from Excel column

Tags: microsoft-excel, selection

I have column with specific data like this

[image: excel sheet]

I need to get data like "00+000" into another column. All other data is useless for me. Is this possible somehow?

Edit: this data is not always rightmost, sometimes it's in the middle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it appears that all the data you want is on the end:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(A1,7))
```

This will get the last 7 characters and then trim the leading space if the first number is only one digit.

---

If it is not always on the end:

```
=TRIM(MID(A1,Find("+",A1)-2,7))
```

Comment: My bad, example not accurate enough. Sometimes the data is in the middle, not only on the end. But if there is no way to do specificly "00+000" extraction, I guess this will do too

Comment: @PeaceFrog see edit.

Comment: This is great, thank you s lot!

Answer (score 1):

As it appears from the sample set you have given, there might not always be a 7 character string to grab, but it is always on the right, and there is a space before it, this might work better for you:

```
=RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","@",LEN(A2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2," ",""))),1))
```

This finds the last space, and grabs the text to the right of it.